# STM8 USART question

Tags: uart, stm8

I am trying to set up UART on a STM8L controller, and I have a code which works only on PC3.
But I want to transmit on PA2, but I don't know why is it not working like this. I don't even initialize the PC3 pin. Is there anything I am missing or is there any way to define pins?
I am working in IAR.

full code:

```
#include <iostm8l151k6.h>
#include <intrinsics.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void InitialiseSystemClock()
{
    CLK_ICKCR = 0;                       //  Reset the Internal Clock Register.
    CLK_ICKCR_HSION = 1;                 //  Enable the HSI.
    CLK_ECKR = 0;                       //  Disable the external clock.
    CLK_CKDIVR = 0;                     //  Ensure the clocks are running at full speed.
    CLK_PCKENR1 = 0xff;                 //  Enable all peripheral clocks.
    CLK_PCKENR2 = 0xff;                 //  Ditto.
    CLK_CCOR = 0;                       //  Turn off CCO.
    CLK_HSITRIMR = 0;                   //  Turn off any HSIU trimming.
    CLK_SWR = 0xe1;                     //  Use HSI as the clock source.
    CLK_SWCR = 0;                       //  Reset the clock switch control register.
    CLK_SWCR_SWEN = 1;                  //  Enable switching.
    while (CLK_SWCR_SWBSY != 0);        //  Pause while the clock switch isbusy.
}

void InitialiseUART()
{
    unsigned char tmp = USART1_SR;
    tmp = USART1_DR;
    USART1_CR1 = 0;
    USART1_CR2 = 0;
    USART1_CR4 = 0;
    USART1_CR3 = 0;
    USART1_CR5 = 0;
    USART1_GTR = 0;
    USART1_PSCR = 0;
    USART1_CR1_M = 0;        //  8 Data bits.
    USART1_CR1_PCEN = 0;     //  Disable parity.
    USART1_CR3_STOP0 = 0;     //  1 stop bit.
    USART1_BRR2 = 0x0a;      //  Set the baud rate registers to 115200 baud
    USART1_BRR1 = 0x08;      //  based upon a 16 MHz system clock.
    USART1_CR2_TEN = 0;      //  Disable transmit.
    USART1_CR2_REN = 0;      //  Disable receive.
    USART1_CR3_CPOL = 1;
    USART1_CR3_CPHA = 1;
    USART1_CR3_LBCL = 1;
    USART1_CR2_TEN = 1;
    USART1_CR2_REN = 1;
    USART1_CR3_CLKEN = 1;
}

void UARTPrintF(char *message)
{
    char *ch = message;
    while (*ch)
    {
        USART1_DR = (unsigned char) *ch;     //  Put the next character into the data transmission register.
        while (USART1_SR_TXE == 0);          //  Wait for transmission to complete.
        ch++;                               //  Grab the next character.
    }
}

void delay(long n)
{
    while (n-- > 0);
}

unsigned char RecUART1(void)
{
    while (!(USART1_SR_RXNE));    // USART_SR[5]:RXNE   Read data register not empty
    PA_ODR |= (1<<2);                                      //   0: Data is not received, 1: Received data is ready to be read.
    return USART1_DR;
}

int main( void )
{
    PA_DDR = 00000100;// TX on PA2
    PA_CR1 = 00000100;
    //out ='l';
    __disable_interrupt();
    InitialiseSystemClock();
    InitialiseUART();
    __enable_interrupt();
    while (1)
    {
        //out = RecUART1();
    PB_ODR = 0; //Turn off all pins
    PB_DDR_DDR4 = 1; //PortB, Bit 4 is output (PD4 - Data Direction Register)
    PB_CR1_C14 = 1; //PortB, Control Register 1, Bit 4 (PD4) set to Push-Pull
    PB_CR2_C24 = 1; //PortB, Control Register 2, Bit 4 (PD4) set to Push-Pull
    PB_ODR = 0x10;
    delay(30000);
        //for (long counter = 0; counter < 250000; counter++);
        //sprintf(dis,"this is %c\n",out);
     char sz[] = "Hello from STM8 \n\r";
     char *z = &sz[0];
     UARTPrintF(z);
     PB_ODR_bit.ODR4 = !PB_ODR_bit.ODR4;
     delay(30000);
    }
}
```

Relevant part of the schematic:
[image]

Comment: Both pins are possibilities for UART1, you will probably need to set an appropriate alternate function configuration for the pin you want, and perhaps unset a default (or inherited from bootloader?) configuration for the pin you do not want.  Read up on the alternate function configuration section / register of the GPIO block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: reference manual]

Thanks to @Chris Stratton, if anybody has the same problem here is the answer